# How can I ask for a prayer request?

Tags: discussion

How can I ask for a prayer request?
I need help for this.

Thank you.

Comment: _Like any library, Christianity Stack Exchange offers great information, but does not offer personalized advice, and does not take the place of seeking such advice from your pastor, priest, or other trustworthy counselor._ This site is an academic site examining _comparative_ Christianity. Please see the Tour and the Help as to the purpose and the functioning of the site.

Comment: @NigelJ, is there any forum to ask for prayer requests? I am really new to the internet.

Comment: I don't, personally, think the internet is the place for that. So I can't assist.

Comment: @NigelJ Any idea what is the different between "Christianity" and "Christianity Beta"?

Comment: 'Christianity Meta' (not Beta) is the administrative support website for the primary 'Christianity' website, in which questions about site function and procedure are asked and answered. I am uncertain why your question was migrated to here, myself.

Comment: It looked like you were asking how to ask a prayer request on this site. If your question is really how to pray in general, well that's more for the main site, but it's also too broad and not focused enough.

Comment: The site needs a big disclaimer at the top: This is not a religious site; it is a site about a religion.

Answer (score 5):

In line with all the comments made so far, this is to make a few general points about the matter of passing on prayer requests on the Internet. As has been said, this Stack Hub is not designed to be a virtual-prayer-shop (to put it colourfully). Questions about prayer in general and prayers recorded in Christian literature can be asked about, but that is not what you are seeking.

When a Christian is in need of getting prayer support from other Christians, then sharing of personal details is required. Enough must be conveyed to people you want to have pray for you as to what they need to pray about. In a one-to-one secure environment (such as a congregation's weekly prayer-meeting) that can be done with little danger to yourself of misunderstanding or of identity fraud.

However, on the Internet, we lay ourselves wide open to that even though we might hold back our real name and location, and not share our e-mail details either. We have no idea who the people are who might pick up on our Internet request. Even if we think we've found a Christian denomination that is agreeable to our understanding of Christianity, that means almost nothing in terms of being assured that they will pray in a way that our Christian conscience might be happy about.

The worst danger is that of unscrupulous people who deliberately trawl the Internet to select individuals they perceive to be vulnerable, to get alongside them and to start grooming them for nefarious purposes. This happens on supposedly 'Christian' sites too.

If you need personal prayer support, there is no substitute for finding local Christians who you can meet and then, if you feel they are trustworthy, to share your prayer requests. I hope you find this helpful, even though this site is not designed to meet such a need. God bless you.